# ¿Cómo usar <asp:UpdateProgress /> para descargar un archivo?

Tags: c#, asp.net

¿Cómo puedo usar el **UpdateProgress** para la acción de descargar un archivo? Ya que al presionar el botón de descarga se muestra el **progressbar**, pero al terminar no se descargar el archivo. El archivo sí se descarga si le quito el **updateprogress**.

Código:

```
public void Descargar()
{
    if (File.Exists(ruta))
    {
        HttpResponse currentResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        currentResponse.Clear();
        currentResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        currentResponse.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombre);
        currentResponse.TransmitFile(ruta.Trim());
        currentResponse.Flush();
        currentResponse.End();
    }
}
```

Vista:

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updFacturas">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="panel panel-success" style="margin-top: 10%; margin-left: 20%; width: 50%;">
                    <div class="panel panel-heading"></div>
                    <div class="panel panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <h4 style="color: brown">Num. de Proyecto:
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtProID" CssClass="form-control" Width="100%" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDescargarFacturas" Text="Descargar Facturas" CssClass="btn btn-success" Width="100%" OnClick="btnDescargarFacturas_Click" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Procesando...<br>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="/Imagenes/ajax-loader.gif" runat="server" />
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Answer (score 1):

creo que le falta la propiedad "AssociatedUpdatePanelID" a tu UpdateProgress...quedaria algo asi:

```
    ...
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updFacturas" DynamicLayout="true">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            Procesando...<br>
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="/Imagenes/ajax-loader.gif" runat="server" />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Saludos!